# Obtaining a basis and its orthogonal basis from a set

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently solving exercises in preparation for exams, the first involves calculating the distance from a point to a set and the second in rewriting a vector as its projection along a basis and an orthogonal basis.

In order to solve these exercises you need to obtain the basis for the sets, and here I am struggling.

- Set $A = \{(2a+1, a-1) : a \in \mathbb{R}\}$
- Set $B = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x-2z=0, x-y+z=0\}$

A) For the first one I have no idea how to obtain a basis, I have thought about decomposing as something such as $(x,y) = a(2,1) + (1,-1)$ but this does not seem to easily generate a basis.

B) I believe I have obtained the basis for this set, since if solving the system of equations you get $x=2z$ and $y=3z$, therefore it should be equivalent to set $F = \{(2a,3a,a): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$, therefore the basis that generates $B$ should be $\langle(2,3,1)\rangle$.

I am however unable to obtain the orthogonal set to $B$, I have attempted to obtain a vector orthogonal to $(2,3,1)$, by inspection I have $(1,-1,1)$, then I calculate a vector orthogonal to both vectors, by calculating $(x,y,z) = (2,3,1) \times (1,-1,1) = (4,-1,-5)$.

It would follow that the basis for $B^\bot$ is $\langle(1,-1,1),(4,-1,-5)\rangle$; however once I try to write $u = \mathit{pr}_B(u) + \mathit{pr}_{B^\bot}(u)$ clearly the right hand side does not equal the left hand side.

Thanks.

Comment: Set A is a line not passing through the origin, you can't find a basis for it. It is parallel to the line a(2,1) passing through the origin. Set B is also a line given as intersection of two planes.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I want to edit my question with the answer to my specific problem before I close the thread, just didn't have the time yet.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **A is a line not passing through the origin**, you can't find a basis for it. It is parallel to the line $a(2,1)$ passing through the origin which is othogonal to the line s(-1,2).

Set **B is a line passing through the origin** given as intersection of two planes. It's othogonal space is given by a plane. You can find it by imposing that it's normal vector is parallel to line B, that is: $$2x+3y+z=0$$

You can also obtain it by the cross product of the two normal vectors of the planes defining B:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
i&j&k\\1&0&-2\\0&1&-3
\end{vmatrix}=2i+3j+k$$

Answer (score 0):

- The set $S$ is not a vector space, so a the concept of basis here is undefined.
- Your basis for $B$ and your basis for $B^{\perp}$ seem to be correct.
- You'll need to share your calculation of the projections for us to be able to help. Do it and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @azthec Please add your reasoning to your question text by editing it. You should elaborate not only on what formula you used, but also on the way you used it: put the numbers in and show the calculation and the final result.

Comment: For the calculation of the projections I followed the [following formula](https://i.imgur.com/yw0YBbg.png).

Comment: Here are my calculation results, for $u = (1,1,1)$:

$ \mathit{pr}_B(u) = (6/14 ,18/14, 6/14)$
$ \mathit{pr}_{B^\bot}(u) = (23/21, 11/21, 9/7)$

Comment: @azthec Please read my comment again. We can't spot you misunderstanding based on the formula and the final answer only. You need to show us your work, and put it in your **question** - not as a comment to my answer.